# How can I make table column titles support other language?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, localization, jtable

When I use table and I want column title can use language encoding UTF-8. But column title can not support language that using unicode.  How can I fix it?

Comment: *"But it can not support language."*  Which language?  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"How can I make table column titles support other language?"*  But the short answer is - use a `Font` that supports the characters used by that language.

Comment: I try change it but it is type unicode UTF-8. it still error.

Comment: *"I try change it but it is type unicode UTF-8."*  I don't even begin to understand that.  But don't try and explain it, [let the code do the talking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *"..it still error."*  Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: I'm beginning to think that you've not bothered following the links and reading about an MCVE/SSCCE.  In short, it is not uncompilable code snippets that are put in code comments (where they are unreadable).

Comment: i read MCVE/SSCCE already. It is my first time build data into jtable so i meet alot of problem. I think you will understand

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too late for this question but I am writing for someone who has this problem.

I had same problem using JavaFx and I fixed it with this way.

First, when you initialize a table and columns, use English. 
and then, use `setText()` to change column title you want.

Below are my code. I hope this would help you out!

```
tcTime = table_schedule.getColumns().get(0); //
tcTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Time")); 
tcTime.setText("string in your language you want column title to name");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code can not support language.​​​

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.addColumn("លេខរៀង");
model.addColumn("ឈ្មោះអតិថិជន");
jTable1.setModel(model);
```